# Como executar uma função somente após uma chamada da API em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, react, axios

Tou preso em uma situação aqui que é a seguinte:

O projeto é feito em React

```
import hostApi from "api/hostApi";

const body = {
    token: localStorage.getItem("suavagaToken")
}

function isAuthenticated() {
    console.log("Chamou a função");
    hostApi.post("empresa/isAuthenticated", body)
        .then(response => {
            localStorage.setItem("suavagaUserIsAuth", response.data)
            console.log("Atualizou o isAuth");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("Erro ao verificar se a empresa está autenticada! :" + err)
        })
}

export default isAuthenticated;
```

```
function checkRouteAuth() {
    isAuthenticated();

    let aux = localStorage.getItem("suavagaUserIsAuth");

    console.log("Variavel aux = " + aux);
    if (aux === "true") {
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Preciso fazer com que minha função checkRouteAuth() tenha sua execução continuada somente após o isAuthenticated() ter terminado. Coloquei os console.log para ver a sequência de execução e aparece o seguinte:

```
Chamou a função         auth.js:8
Variavel aux = false    Routes.jsx:14
Atualizou o isAuth      auth.js:12
```

Ou seja, o log "Atualizou o isAuth" está sendo executado antes do "Variavel aux", assim o aux não atualiza em tempo de execução. Como solucionar isso?

Comment: Aqui tem um artigo que pode te ajudar https://imasters.com.br/front-end/entenda-tudo-sobre-asyncawait

Comment: Também pode dar uma olhada em  `promise chaining`.

Comment: Ainda não entendi como seria para colocar async/await no meu código

Answer (score 1):

Poderia utilizar `async/await` para que o resto da função `checkRouteAuth()` espera a conclusão de `isAuthenticated()`.

```
async function checkRouteAuth() {
    await isAuthenticated();

    let aux = localStorage.getItem("suavagaUserIsAuth");

    console.log("Variavel aux = " + aux);
    if (aux === "true") {
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Lembrando que isso significa que sua função `checkRouteAuth()` agora retornaria um `Promise<boolean>`.

***Atualização***

Teria que também retornar a promise `return hostApi.post...` dentro da função `isAuthenticated()`

Comment: Não mudou o resultado e ainda aparece a anotação "'await' has no effect on the type of this expression" no await

Comment: Tem que tornar `isAuthenticated()` async e dentro de `checkRouteAuth()` a aguardar.

Comment: ta certo poderia também. Poderia também coloca ` return hostApi.post...` dentro de `isAuthenticated()`

Comment: @AugustoVasques atualizei minha resposta, coloquei Await na função errada

Comment: Ainda falta modificar essa função `function isAuthenticated()` e sua assinatura.

Comment: @AugustoVasques nao e preciso coloca await em `isAuthenticated()`.  `async/await` basicamente so retorna um `promise`.  Ja estamos retornado um promise em `isAuthenticated()` se colocamos `return hostApi.post...`